# Prove $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\left(tx\right)=\langle \nabla f\left(tx\right),x \rangle $

Tags: calculus

let $ f :\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $ and prove that for any $ t \in \mathbb{R} $ the following equality holds:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\left(tx\right)=\langle\nabla f\left(tx\right),x\rangle.$$

I'm not sure how to start because I don't know which of the following would be the right way to right the deriavtive:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\left(tx\right)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}\left(tx\right)x_{1}+\ldots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n}}\left(tx\right)x_{n} $$

or

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\left(tx\right)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\left(tx_{1}\right)}\left(tx\right)x_{1}+\ldots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\left(tx_{n}\right)}\left(tx\right)x_{n} $$

Comment: The first one: it's the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While understandable, the notation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(tx)$ is actually quite "bad", and confusing.

Let me rephrase your problem a bit. Consider a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. Define the function $g:\mathbb{R}\times{\mathbb{R}}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ with $g(t,x)=f(tx)$. Find
$
\frac{\partial }{\partial t}g(t,x).
$

When applying the chain rule, the [Leibniz notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz%27s_notation) of derivatives could be confusing, in particular without an explicit choice of the "intermediate variable".

It is revealing to look at the case when $n=1$.

By the chain rule, you have
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial t}g(t,x)=f'(tx)\cdot x=\frac{df}{d\color{red}{z}}\bigg|_{\color{red}{z}=tx}\cdot x
$$
where we explicitly write the variable for the function $f$ as $z$.

In the higher dimension, you have
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial t}g(t,x)=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\color{red}{z_1}}\bigg|_{\color{red}{z}=tx}\cdot x_1
+\cdots
+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\color{red}{z_n}}\bigg|_{\color{red}{z}=tx}\cdot x_n
=
\langle
\nabla f(tx),x\rangle$$

Sometimes, people simply write

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial t}g(t,x)=
\partial_1f(tx)\cdot x_1
+\cdots
+\partial_nf(tx)\cdot x_n
=
\langle
\nabla f(tx),x\rangle$$